# Disable/Enable Images in Comments on Facebook (Profile Posts, not Pages)

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I know Facebook pages have the ability for admins to [disable photos in comments](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10204075569423648) which says to do so by disabling photo/video posts to a page's timeline (which seems counter-intuitive, but I digress).

However, there appears to be no way to enable or disable photos in comments on personal posts (comments for profile posts or album photos not associated with a page).

Seems like it can be done though, because I have friends with personal posts to which I cannot attach a photo in the comments. One friend, in particular, isn't sure how it happened, but wants to re-enable that ability and neither of us can figure out how. Everyone seems stumped according to my Google search, and Facebook's support system is littered with people asking the same question but never getting any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Personal posts work differently to facebook pages, [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82653/dont-allow-comments-on-facebook-page/82700#82700) refers to automatically hiding all comments but won't work for photos alone.

On a personal profile you are just restricting who can post on your timeline, or who can view photos which are tagged with your name. I think the photo tagging option are what you are looking for.

Go to your **Settings** then **Timeline and Tagging** and check these settings

- Who can post on your timeline?
- Review posts friends tag you in before they appear on your timeline?
- Who can see posts you've been tagged in on your timeline?
- Who can see what others post on your timeline?

There isn't an option to prevent comments on individual photos, only to restrict who can see or post photos of you on your timeline (or tag you in photos on their timeline)

[facebook help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/267508226592992)

Comment: If you read the question carefully, I'm not talking about disabling comments on photos, I'm talking about enabling/disabling photos IN comments.

Comment: other than disabling photos this can't be done -  especially since a comment including a link to the photo would display a preview of the photo

Comment: It can be done because I am trying to help someone enable photos in comments on his posts where they currently appear to be disabled, but he can't remember what he did to disable them.

Comment: @purefusion check the settings I pointed out in the answer

Comment: They don't seem to make any difference with respect to photos in comments.