# Don't allow comments on Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Is there any way to not allow people commenting on posts of my Facebook page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Facebook hasn't enabled a way to disable comments on pages.

People have already asked this question on Facebook Help Page and the answer provided by Facebook Help Team is [How do I allow or disable posts by other people on my Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/356113237741414/?ref=u2u)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Disabling comments** this is for preventing replies to your posts which would appear under your posts. There is no facebook feature to do this but there is a [workaround](http://www.pcsteps.com/2273-disable-comments-on-a-facebook-page/) which automatically hides are comments -  so they are visible to only the person who wrote them and their friends list.

**Instructions**

In your page's **Settings,** go to **General**, then **Page Moderation**.

Add very common words to the moderation box with commas between them, eg **a, the, and, like, it, to**

A long list of common English words can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxu8unle-0U0eXpNLS1oMDBWVTg/view) and copied across. It's also a good idea to add common 'words' used to avoid moderation and used by spammers, or text speak/emojis, eg **lol, lmao, rofl, <3, (y), p0rn, p3n1s, pen1s, viagra, h0t, xxx, x, xxxx, click, buy, offer, win, sale, watch**

Next go to **Profanity Filter** and set it to Strong to block even more words.

Regular comments can be prevented from posting by finding on of their comments and using **Ban user** to add them to your ban list.

2. **Disabling posts on your page's timeline.** This mostly deals with posts from other facebook pages or bloggers linking to their own pages. The [information from facebook's help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/356113237741414/?ref=u2u) has changed in the last week, although I'm not sure when this feature was available from.

It can now be done from a desktop computer using https://www.facebook.com/yourpagename/settings/?tab=settings&view - go to Visitor Posts and you have different options:

- Allow Photos and Comments
- Notify me so I can Review posts before they appear on the page
- Do not allow Visitors to post to the page

  3. **Preventing ratings and reviews** [instructions](https://www.facebook.com/help/1380944052155150)

**Lastly,** a custom [user script](http://userscripts.org/) can be used to automatically delete all comments without you needing to view them,it would only run when you visit the page from your local machine (or another machine with the script installed). You need to install Greasemonkey (for Firefox) or Tampermonkey to set this up. If a userscript isn't already there for it then you would need to write your own (many facebook exampls there).

Comment: _There is no Facebook feature to do this_ in first point says the same thing what I have already written in my answer.  OP is not asking to hide comment. **Disabling comment**, **hiding comment** and **disabling post on page's timeline**, all are different. Please do not mislead, there is not feature to disable comments on pages.